# SSH terminal window hangs when command output is wide and long

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, gnome-terminal

I am using Tilix on Ubuntu, updated and upgrade. I am accessing a Debian machine, updated and upgraded.

Everything works fine, except when I fire a command which has lot of output, usually horizontally laid out such as `docker ps -a` or `ip a s`, it just hangs.

If I decrease text size to make it look smaller before firing command, the command works fine, but fails with normal font-size. But this is not sure shot, and fails next time anyway.

```bsh
Versions
    Tilix version: 1.9.4
    VTE version: 0.62
    GTK Version: 3.24.25
```

Ubuntu: 5.11.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 7 14:22:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Debian: 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Works with smaller fonts:
[image: Works with smaller fonts]

Hung
[image: Hung]

Hung with small fonts
[image: Hung with small fonts]

I have tried `ENTER ~.` and `ctrl+d|z|c|x` and basically hitting every key. Have to kill the terminal window.

Please help.

Comment: When working with distance machines which have a bad internet connection use a terminal buffer program like `screen`. So you do _ssh_ like you'll do all the time to that machine, but the first command you'll execute is `screen`. `screen` will open a **local** terminal which will remain opened when the connection breaks. `screen` is very error tolerant, even if the connection should break, you may just reconnect via ssh and relogin into your **local** `screen` terminal.

Comment: This look to me like a tilix issue, rather than ssh or gnome terminal. I suggest editing the title of your question to reflect this.